# How to Find The CID of an Attachment in Owl PHPMailer?

Tags: image, phpmailer, inline

I'm trying to include and inline image of my attachment in my HTML body using Owl PHPMailer 1.6.

I want to find the CID for the attached images I uploaded, in order to inline include it as so: 
    `<img src='cid:my-image'>`

How to find the CID of the attached images?

Comment: I've no idea what "Owl PHPMailer" is, but I assume it's using PHPMailer somehow. `cid` values are entirely up to you. Look at the `addEmbeddedImage` method; you'll see it allows you to specify a `cid` value for the image, which you can then reference in your image tags.

Comment: @Synchro https://sourceforge.net/projects/owl-phpmailer/ Check it here!

Comment: @Synchro I want to find the CID without having to gr through the code, if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Owl PHPMailer code, I see that it does not do image embedding (only regular attachments), so it doesn't generate `cid` values for you to find.

Net result, you can't do what you ask.

PHPMailer itself has support for doing this, but Owl PHPMailer does not make use of or expose that ability.

I'd recommend asking the authors of Owl PHPMailer to add it.